# if a sequence is square summable can its sum oscillate between +/- infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a real-valued sequence such that $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n^2 < \infty$. Put $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$.

My question is, is it possible for $\limsup_n S_n = \infty$ and $\liminf_n S_n = -\infty$? That is, can the sequence infinitely oscillate between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$?

If $a_n = 1/n$, then clearly $\limsup_n S_n = \infty$. But if $a_n = (-1)^n 1/n$ then we know the sequence converges, hence the question.

Comment: How does the $\limsup$ of $\frac{1}{n}$ equal $\infty$? The sequence converges to $0$ and it is bounded above by $1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim \sup S_n$ and $\lim \inf S_n$?

Comment: Yes thanks, fixed.

Comment: I believe you meant $S_n$ instead of $a_n$, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Note that a finite sequence of value $\pm 1/m$ repeated $m$ times has $\sum t_n = \pm 1 $ 
and $\sum t_n^2 =  1/m$.  Put these together with $m$ growing rapidly...